# IIS 6 ASP.NET handler 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, httphandler

I have an IIS6 running on Windows Server 2003 (x86) and have written a custom handler (Not a handler for 404 errors).

When I try to access the handler by opening in a browser http://localhost/Priority1.Sync/Transfer.p1s, I get error 404 (404 0 in log file). Other pages in the web application work, e.g. http://localhost/priority1.sync/syncservice.asmx

The handler works fine on my IIS7 dev machine.

web.config is setup as follows:

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.p1s" type="MCS.Priority1.Sync.WebServices.TransferHandler, SyncService" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I have set an application extension for "*.p1s" (Default Web Site>Properties>Home Directory>Configuration>Mappings>Add).

Am I missing something else?

Thanks, 
Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the "Verify that file exists" option in your custom handler IIS configuration checked or not?

IIS6 expects a physical file to exist by default. If there isn't one, it won't pass the request on to your handler at all. You need to disable this check, so it will send the request to your handler as expected.

Comment: Got it in 1, thanks.
Specifically, when I went to [Default Web Site>Properties>Home Directory>Configuration>Mappings>Add], I should have unchecked the "Verify that file exists" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

IIS6 and IIS7 are fundamentally different beasts. IIS7's managed pipeline means every request hits your registered handlers, in IIS6 only things mapped to ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL (typically *.aspx and *.ashx and other default ASP.NET extensions) get processed.

You can make your IIS7 dev box behave this way by using the "classic" pipeline for your development app pool for this project.

Another trick to making it work how you expect is to map 404 errors to an ASP.NET page and then you can at least get into your handler.

In all honesty I would look towards upgrading production to IIS7 as it is so vastly more capable it isn't even funny.

Answer (score 1):

If you are registering handlers for IIS 6 then do remember they should be placed in the 
`<httpHandlers>` element of `<system.web>` section of the web.config not the `<system.webServer>` section that IIS7 uses.